# append newline character to message in shell / linux for mail command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email, newline

What is the best way to append a new line to a message and then send that per mail?

```
message=""

for f in $backupdir/*; do
    message+="..."
done
echo "$message" | mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "[Test]" email
```

i found `message+="message"$'\n'` but this has some bugs when opening that mail in outlook
i tried mailx with html tag but this does not append a new line at all.

Comment: have you tried `<br />` when using html?

Comment: You are already using  `message+="..."` inside the loop; what's preventing you from doing `message+=$'\n'` after the loop? (The entire loop is dubious, though: why do you not simply `echo` the lines and pipe the output from `done` to `mailx`?)

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML, you can put the `<br />` tag in the message.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32009149)

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara: Why not?

Answer (score 0):

> i found message+="message"$'\n' but this has some bugs when opening that mail in outlook

The reason for this is because you asks mailx to encode the mail into HTML.

if you need an HTML email, then you need to compose HTML paragraphs

```bash
message="${message}<p>Some new paragraph.</p>"
# ...
printf %s "$message" | mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s '[Test]' email@example.com
```

Now if you want to send plain text messages, regular newlines are just fine:

```bash
message="${message}Some new paragraph.
"
# Or Bash's c-style string to add the newline and concatenate string
message+=$'Another paragraph\n'
 printf %s "$message" | mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/plain' -s '[Test]' email@example.com
```